# Calculate average in excel for different items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have information about measurements of network performance that I'd extracted from a DB, that table is really long and I doesn't allow me to group by each test category and then calculate the average of each test, so I extracted the information to excel of each measure and now I need to take the average by test, which formula could I use?

```
18707   Ping - Average - VALVE:dsl  196
18651   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):dsl  150
18689   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):dsl    22
3914    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  156
14737   Ping - Average - Internacional (neutralidad-internacional.movistarplay.cl):fija 106
15213   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):fija 137
15283   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):fija   218
27445   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):movil    157
27483   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):movil  248
6109    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  143
6144    Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com)    244
22259   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.89.139 )  48
22250   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.5.139 )   37
14167   Ping - Average - DNS - GVT  39
2710    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  210
21047   Ping - Average Latency - Blizzard (HeartStone)  50
7250    Ping - Average Latency - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  147
7286    Ping - Average Latency - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com)    39
3061    Ping - Average - Internacional (neutralidad-internacional.movistarplay.cl)  130
3061    Ping - Average - Internacional (neutralidad-internacional.movistarplay.cl)  120
15213   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):fija 132
15283   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):fija   229
12237   Ping - Average - VALVE  184
5182    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  132
5201    Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com)    15
3304    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  124
6424    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  116
30047   Ping - Average - Netflix 1080:sin NF    42
27037   Ping - Average - YouTube 1080p:sin NF   68
27027   Ping - Average - YouTube 4K:sin NF  69
27017   Ping - Average - YouTube 720p:sin NF    70
27007   Ping - Average - YouTube Automatic Quality:sin NF   68
26997   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):sin NF   169
22259   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.89.139 )  21
22250   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.5.139 )   21
14167   Ping - Average - DNS - GVT  79
2710    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  192
6109    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  194
6144    Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com)    441
22259   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.89.139 )  19
22250   Ping - Average - DNS Resolution ( 200.175.5.139 )   8
14167   Ping - Average - DNS - GVT  8
2710    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  172
6109    Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com)  307
6144    Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com)    348
15213   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):fija 194
15283   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):fija   292
14737   Ping - Average - Internacional (neutralidad-internacional.movistarplay.cl):fija 117
27445   Ping - Average - Internacional (www.terremark.com):movil    157
27483   Ping - Average - League of Legends (prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com):movil  251
18707   Ping - Average - VALVE:dsl  204
```

Notice that the first column is the primary key that identifies that test, the second is the name of the test and the third column is the value that test.

I need to calculate the average but not of the whole sheet but of each test.

Comment: I wish to average numbers on the extreme right and match it just with its monitor ignoring all the others, for example, first row includes the monitor id 18707 and the last row is also the monitor id 18707, i want to average 196 and 204 and ignore the others ones, and that for each test.

Comment: You can add an extra column, use `AVERAGEIF` and then choose the whole table and use "Remove Duplicates" by the monitor column

Comment: @pnuts: yes, the result by each monitor.

Comment: @GalAbra: After i select the whole table the remove duplicates option is not available

Comment: @DavidSalasBoscan Not available or not working as expected?

Comment: I did =averageif(
then select the whole table and the duplicated value option is in grey in excel just cannot click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column, then put in each cell:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, A1, B:B)
```

- `A:A` - Monitor column
- `A1` - The cell to add to average (the number represents the row)
- `B:B` - The column you want to average

Then choose the whole table and use "Remove Duplicates" by the monitor column.

Comment: @DavidSalasBoscan Did you adjust the columns? Maybe one of your monitor column cells is empty?